# Remove Rafter Ties Pergola

Tags: roofing, pergola

I bought a house that appears to have a pergola converted into a sunroom.  It's supported by exposed 6x6s with 2x12 beams on which a roof was added at some point (likely later). The whole thing was drywalled so I can't see how the roof was tied. I'm remodeling the room and it would be nice to remove the rafter ties if they aren't needed.  I will hire an engineer to help (when I can find one) before I do anything but I wanted to get opinions on if this is even recommended or if I need to just live with it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rafters are effectively hinged at the ridge, where the ties resist the outward force brought on by downward pressure on the roof. If you convert your 2x12 pairs into structural boxes, then they could act as horizontal beams fighting that outward force. Under this idea, you could reduce the frequency of the rafter ties and maybe even eliminate them totally (the current frequency looks excessive, where analysis would probably allow some ties to be removed without any other work). The eccentricity of the rafters from the center of such a box is analytically annoying, where I expect that a designer might require some "kickers" bracing the box against torsion.

If the current pairs of 2×12s were sized properly, then 2 2×12s of the same grade and species would be an adequate ridge beam to eliminate the ties. This cuts both ways, where oversized pairs of 2×12s imply that a smaller ridge beam would still be adequate. At least one end is above a sliding glass door it appears, so at least one substantial header would be necessary to carry the end load of the ridge beam down to the foundation. Installation in plane with the rafters sounds painful, where the ridge beam would probably carry the rafters in bearing from below.

Some collar ties closer to the ridge could replace the rafter ties. In the limit, you could install some sufficiently thick and tall gusset plates up at the ridge. It could be difficult to get them small enough to disappear beneath the drywall.